# generalise unit testing for private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, testng

I have a private method where I do all my validation and this method takes a generic object as input parameter. This private method is called by 10 public methods passing the specific object which is the subclass of the generic object mentioned the parameter list of the private method.

How do I write a generic test suite for testing the private method and then invoke this method by all the 10 different public methods so that I do not duplicate the validation in each of the public test methods.

I am using testng and mockito for testing.

Comment: Don't just describe what your code looks like. Post the structure of the classes involved (and ***not*** implementation details which are irrelevant to the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Only the API should be unit tested.
 Private methods are not part of the API.

As your validation method has a central role and that it performs a specific task (validation), I think that to improve the quality of your unit tests and of your design in general, you should refactor your actual design.

You could for example introduce a new class (`Validation` for example) and extract this private method into `Validation` class as a public method.
In your actual class, add a dependency on the `Validation` class by including an instance field of it :

```
public class MyClass{
  ...
  private Validation validation;
     MyClass(Validation validation){
       this.validation = validation;
     }
  ...
}
```

In this way, you could unit test Validation a single time and mock it in the user class.

Comment: The principle of moving the functionality out is right but I'm skeptical of "Validation" as an object. Right now I'm thinking it would make more sense to have `Foo` and `ValidFoo` classes but OP's description is incredibly vague.

Comment: @Michael you are right about naming. Without op context, maybe `MyValidation` would be better as it is symmetric with `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

UnitTests verify the *public observable behavior* through the *public interface* of the object.

Your private method is an implementation detail which you do not test explicitly.

If you feel that  10+ test cases should not cover this part of your code then you might consider moving it to a (new) *service class* (no, not the kind with static methods...)  and passing that in as a dependency using *dependency injection*.

Then you can replace the service class for testing with a *mock* (without the help of <strike>PowerMock</strike>) and verify that the 10+ test cases call the dependency.

You can also verify the behavior of the new service class with its own set of unit test.